# Check value of nested json key

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key-value

I would like to compare the value of a key from a JSON file to see if I have recorded data from todays date by seeing if the current date exists in the file so i don't record data from the same day. But this method seems to return False even if the date is present.

```
def removeJsonDupes(JSONcompleteFilePath, date):
    with open(JSONcompleteFilePath, "r") as file:
        dictionary = json.load(file)
        if dictionary.get("date") is str(date):
            dateRecorded = True
            print(date, "is in the dict")
        else:
            dateRecorded = False
            print(date, "is not in the dict")

return dateRecorded
```

JSON content:

```
{
     "prices": [
        {
            "date": "07/12/21",
            "prices": [
                "2.49",
                "1.61"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @TheFlyingObject's answer, the `date` key you are trying to retrieve is nested inside the dictionary.

In order to access it, you need to first get the key it is stored in (that is the `prices` key which holds a list) and then iterate over the objects in that list.

For example:

```
for i in dictionary['prices']:
    if i['date'] is str(date):
        print(date, 'is in the dict')
        return True
# we finished going over the list inside the prices key, and didn't find the date we were looking for
print(date, 'is not in the dict')
return False
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dictionary.get()` looks for keys and you only have the `prices` key. The key `date` is in the value of the `prices` key.

Answer (score 0):

Change function as follows

```
def removeJsonDupes(JSONcompleteFilePath, date):
    with open(JSONcompleteFilePath, "r") as file:
        dictionary = json.load(file)
        if dictionary.get('prices')[0]['date'] is str(date): # condition changed
            dateRecorded = True
            print(date, "is in the dict")
        else:
            dateRecorded = False
            print(date, "is not in the dict")

    return dateRecorded
```

Will give following result

```
dictionary = {
     "prices": [
        {
            "date": "07/12/21",
            "prices": [
                "2.49",
                "1.61"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

removeJsonDupes(dictionary, "07/12/21")
# 07/12/21 is in the dict

removeJsonDupes(dictionary, "07/12/22")
# 07/12/22 is not in the dict
```